# how to open a html page in browser when any user connect to raspberry pi hotspot without captive portal or free radius

Tags: raspberry-pi3, hotspot

I set up a hotspot on raspberry pi via this link:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

and I want to open an HTML welcome page in the user's browser on the link: `localhost:80` when any user connects to a Raspberry Pi hotspot without a captive portal or any software program.

Note: I am using Raspbian Buster lite.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open an HTML Welcome pages on the user's browser on the link: localhost:80 when any user connects to Raspberry Pi hotspot.

As you said, you need a **splash page** for the clients and it's part of a captive portal mechanism. I suggest you [NoDogSplash](https://nodogsplashdocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
By [THIS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88438/raspberry-pi-as-access-point-with-captive-portal/106018?__=1379994301#106018) link, you will not get stuck on installation.